# Can't figure out how to properly zoom in on the entire webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, zooming

I need to zoom-in on entire page so that it looks something like [this](http://www.schuchmann-wines.com/travel/).

I know I can do this on hover, using the following css:

```
.cycle-slideshow img:hover {
   transform: scale(1.25);
   transition: 20s;
}
```

But I'm not sure how to do that on a page load, without enlarging the images itself. Would appreciate some advises. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use keyframes to make it zoom in.

**CSS:**

```
@keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1.0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1.25);
    }
}
```

Then you just call the animation wherever you want to apply it:

```
#image-container {
    width: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
}    
#myImage {
    animation: imageAnimation 20s infinite alternate;
    width: 600px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="image-container">
    <img id="myImage" src="myimage.jpg" alt="Image">
</div>
```

Here is a working [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/Hunter377/6ewubr0a/2/).
You can read more about keyframes and how there work [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I've been looking for!

Comment: No problem! Please don't forget to approve this answer so that other people with the same problem can quickly find a solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, it turns out that you have to have reputation of at least 15 to be able to approve answers and since I am new here and currently do not have needed reputation, I am unable to do that...

Comment: @M.Pr. Upvoting is different than approving an answer. You can approve an answer with just 1 rep, you need 15 to upvote. Please look at the top left and click the check mark if this answer was helpful to you, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the image inside a div then make the overflow of the div hidden, see this demo

```css
#container{
  height: 400px;
  width: 800px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
img{
  transition: 40s;
}
#container:hover img{
  transform: scale(2, 2)
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="http://www.schuchmann-wines.com/travel/wp-content/uploads/sites/5/2015/08/kazbegibackpack.jpg" alt="" height="400" width="800" />
</div>
```